# How to show two different collections with two different templates sorted by time in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm pretty much a beginner and I'm using Meteor for a quick prototype we are using for UX testing at work. (UX designer does coding, yay).

Now here is the problem, I have two collections with two templates: `Comments` and `Tasks`. I want to show a combined view of these two sorted by creation date. Right now I am only able to first show comments and after that show the tasks, with their respective templates simply by doing:

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
    {{#if comments.count}}
        {{#each comments}}
            {{> comment}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <li class="empty">
            <h1>No comments yet :(</h1>
            {{#if currentUser}}
                <p>Why don't you <span class="write-comment">write one?</span></p>
            {{else}}
                <p>Log in to write a new one.</p>
            {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/if}}
    {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Is there a way to simply "unify" the view? I am doing everything locally on the client without any server-side things and no security, since it is all done locally on a test system with a moderator sitting next to the test subject, so I left it unsecure and autopublish on for a very quick prototype.

I guess a way would be to put the comments and the tasks into an array and sort it in there before displaying, but would that still be reactive and work?

I am also lost on the syntax for that I have to say.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you can write a helper which combines both of them. Since it is a helper it will be reactive, if you query on collections (or any reactive data sources) in that helper.

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    items: function () {
        // get comments and tasks - Add appropriate query properties to filter results
        var comments = Comments.find({}).fetch();
        var tasks = Tasks.find({}).fetch();

        //Add a property to each comment object to identify whether an item is a comment or task 
        comments = _.map(comments, function (obj) {
            obj.isComment = true;
            return obj;
        });

        //combine comments and tasks into single array
        var items = comments.concat(tasks);

        //sort combined array by creation date
        items = _.sortBy(items, function (item) {
            return item.creationDate; //edit this based on your requirement
        });
        return items;
    }
});
```

Then in your template

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
    {{#if items.count}}
        {{#each items}}
            <!-- This is the property that we have added in helper -->
            {{#if this.isComment}}
                {{> comment}}
            {{else}}
                {{> task}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <li class="empty">
            <h1>No comments and tasks yet :(</h1>
            {{#if currentUser}}
                <p>Why don't you <span class="write-comment">write a comment?</span></p>
            {{else}}
                <p>Log in to write a new comment.</p>
            {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked perfect and was exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much, the help is really appreciated!

Comment: @GüntherFeldbaumer Good to know that it worked. Can you accept it as answer. :)